# Why Do We Divide By 2 When We Pick Two Teams of 5 Out of 10, But Not When We Pick One Team of 5?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

So I am trying to learn and improve my counting and combinatorics skills. I noticed that during a problem that when I choose two teams of 5 out of 10, I have to divide by two to account for double counting. However, we I do it for only one team, I just do a simple 10 choose 5 (10C5).

Why is that?

Comment: Do it for picking a team of $2$ from a set of $4$, say {$a,b,c,d$}. Picking one team there are $6$ such teams: $ab; ac; ad; bc; bd; cd$. But picking two teams of $2$, the six just picked get paired up by complements giving these $3$ pairs of teams: [$ab,cd$] ; [$ac,bd$] ; [$ad,bc$].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because in the case of one team, the chosen five and the unchosen five are not interchangeable.  For example the chosen five are going to the Olympics, and the other 5 stay home...although perhaps now everybody stays home).

But in the case of two teams of $5$, the two groups of five are interchangeable because the two teams play the same role--that is: being a team of five (perhaps to play basketball against each other).

Comment: That clarified it. Than you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to provide some insight.

Suppose we had a few teams, A, B, and C and we wanted to choose two of them. If we wanted to look at ALL the ways we can choose 2 teams, we would have:

(A,B)  (B,A)

(A,C)  (C,A)

(B,C)  (C,B)

But choosing teams (A, B) is really the same as choosing teams (B, A) in this scenario... so let's get rid of the right column:

(A,B)

(A,C)

(B,C)

You can see we are left with half.

Now, suppose we had a few teams A, B, C. Let's look at all the ways we can select 1 team from those....

We can select A, B, or C. There is no double counting in this scenario, so no need to divide!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\text{Scenario 1} & \text{Team A} & \text{Team B}\\
\hline
\text{Scenario 2} & \text{Team B} & \text{Team A}\\
\hline
\end{array}
Both scenarios render the same outcome:  Team A faces off against Team B.